# Redirect output meant for a file to a bash variable instead

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I'm using bash to start a headless browser and would like the output meant for a file redirect and stored in a bash variable instead of file.

I can get the command below to work it outputs to a file:

```
chromium-browser --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1' --headless --proxy-server='direct://' --proxy-bypass-list=* --no-proxy-server --dump-dom http://google.com > webpage_data.txt
```

But I would like the output piped to a variable instead of a file

I tried the code below but it didn't work.  I'm trying not to create a file for this output.

```
html=chromium-browser --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1' --headless --proxy-server='direct://' --proxy-bypass-list=* --no-proxy-server --dump-dom http://google.com
```

Also this

```
chromium-browser --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1' --headless --proxy-server='direct://' --proxy-bypass-list=* --no-proxy-server --dump-dom http://google.com > html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
html=$(chromium-browser --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 \(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X\) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1' --headless --proxy-server='direct://' --proxy-bypass-list=* --no-proxy-server --dump-dom http://google.com)
```

You might need to escape a few characters inside the brackets. Though, I have already escaped `(` and `)` but in case it fails still.

Comment: If it is in `'`, it need not be escaped (in this context).

Comment: Not only that; the quoted string will include the literal backslashes.